# Term for language status

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm working on a project trying to define the relation between languages and countries. A detail on that is specifying the *status* of a language in a particular country. I defined four-level classification and named three of them. Probably due to being the most "neutral" of statuses, I'm having a hard time naming the third one. They are:

- **Official:** The language is formally accepted and used for the functioning of the national state/government organs.
- **Recognized:** Formal education and services are available in the language. Local/regional governments use it as an additional official language.
- *[Something]:* The language is used in daily life and private education & services are provided in it. The state/government is mostly uninvolved.
- **Suppressed:** The state or general public covertly or overtly adopts a negative stance against use of the language. Users may be derided, harassed or prosecuted.

I need a single-word name for the third status in there, in line with the others. Terms like *"Neutral"* seemed weak among the other three, as well as negated terms (*non-x*, *un-x*).

Another criterion is that this term should not imply the size of population using the language, so terms like *minority* and *common* don't work well either.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108716/discussion-on-question-by-edgerunner-term-for-language-status).

Answer (score 2):

How about **accepted**? From M-W:

> **[accepted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accepted)**: generally approved or used. e.g., an accepted convention/practice

This seems to fit the bill nicely. It's clearly below *official* and *recognized* and above *suppressed*. It pretty much calls your third category what it is.

**Addendum**: Another possibility is **permitted**. From M-W:

> **[permit](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/permit)**: to consent to expressly or formally

As per the comments below, I would say **permitted** is less positive than *accepted* but more positive than *tolerated*. Ditto re **allowed**, which in the context of your question means the same thing  as **permitted**.

Of the choices I've suggested, I think **permitted** works the best:

> **Official**: The language is formally accepted and used for the functioning of the national state/government organs.
>
> **Recognized**: Formal education and services are available in the language. Local/regional governments use it as an additional official language.
>
> **Permitted**: The language is used in daily life and private education & services are provided in it. The state/government is mostly uninvolved.
>
> **Suppressed**: The state or general public covertly or overtly adopts a negative stance against use of the language. Users may be derided, harassed or prosecuted.

Comment: That was one of the first options I considered, along with "tolerated", I guess I'm looking for something between those two. "Accepted" seems too close to "Recognized" while "tolerated" is definitely negative.

Comment: @edgerunner How about *allowed*? Less positive than *accepted* but more positive than *tolerated*. I could add it to my answer, if you'd like.

Comment: @edgerunner Another possibility is *permitted*. What do you think?

Comment: In the societies that respect certain basic freedoms, the use of **any** language is permitted. For example, the use of Klingon is permitted in the United Kingdom, but that's not what the OP has in mind.

Comment: @jsw29 I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @jsw29 exactly.

Comment: “At will.” In some countries any language can be spoken, taught, used in whatever way people choose. E.g., a newspaper can be published in the language. “Unregulated” may be another term.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has an article titled [List of largest languages without official status.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_languages_without_official_status)
The OECD (Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development) glossary of statistical terms defines [Non-official language](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=5591), or [Unofficial language](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=7096).

> A language that, though relatively widely used, lacks officially sanctioned status in a particular legally constituted political entity. Example: French in Lebanon; English in Israel.

So it sounds like **non-official language** is an acceptable phrase.

OECD itself references a broken link from Statistics Canada, but we can see that they use the phrase **non-official language** in the following example: [Statistics Canada 2016 census data on knowledge of languages](https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/dt-td/Rp-eng.cfm?TABID=2&Lang=E&APATH=3&DETAIL=0&DIM=0&FL=A&FREE=0&GC=0&GID=1235625&GK=0&GRP=1&PID=110463&PRID=10&PTYPE=109445&S=0&SHOWALL=0&SUB=0&Temporal=2016&THEME=118&VID=0&VNAMEE=&VNAMEF=&D1=0&D2=0&D3=0&D4=0&D5=0&D6=0)

I would be careful how you define suppressed languages, because there is some overlap between your definition of a non-official language and a suppressed language, for instance a language that is shunned by the general public while the state has no policy toward it.

Comment: This sounds like the correct definition although I'd rather avoid the antonyms of my three other terms. Maybe a synonym of unofficial would do the trick.

Comment: The phrases such as *unofficial language* and *non-official language* can serve the OP's purpose only if the context makes it clear that they refer to a language that is not official **but** still widely used in a particular country. A typical sentence in which they will be understood in the way that is intended here is something like 'X is the unofficial language **of** Y': note that 'of Y' is needed to convey the idea that the language has some special connection with Y. Apart from such a context, an unofficial language is **any** language that is not official.

Answer (score 1):

**Colloquial**

From M-W:

*1:  Used in or characteristic of conversation, especially familiar and informal conversation*

Quite simply, it refers to the language people actually use, regardless of whether it is officially sanctioned or not in any way.

Comment: *Colloquial* is normally used in contrast with *formal*, and the distinction between colloquial and formal use of a language is independent of the distinctions that the OP is trying to draw.

Answer (score 1):

In sociolinguistics and linguistic anthropology **vernacular** is the term most often used for a language learned and used in the home, used in informal settings including some services, and in everyday situations, but that is not a language used by the state, isn't a language in which formal education occurs, isn't considered a "literary" language, or is otherwise viewed as not an "official" language.*

Some of the definitions on [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/vernacular) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vernacular) reflect such usage. The paper “Diglossia: Separate and Unequal”† goes into this a bit but unfortunately isn't publicly available. Another piece called [“Why Ethnography?”](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eeckert/PDF/whyethnography.pdf)‡ by the same author *is* publicly accessible and does talk about vernacular usage as compared to official usage (in the context of an educational institution), but the comparison between vernacular and official language is not draw explicitly the way it is in the work on [diglossia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diglossia) (which is itself a term referring to the compartmentalization of different language varieties in terms of the contexts in which they're viewed as acceptably usable and which also corresponds to their arrangement in a status hierarchy where the lower-status variety is invariably the vernacular).

---

* Note that "language" here is not actually a well-defined term; some vernaculars are what people often call "dialects," e.g. AAVE, some are different languages altogether in that they're not mutually intelligible, and others are in between. For this reason it's probably more precise to refer to official versions, dialects, registers, and even accents as language "varieties," which also has a more neutral connotation. So a vernacular is one language variety among many used by the people in any particular population that shares linguistic norms or features.

† Eckert, Penelope. 1980. “Diglossia: Separate and Unequal.” *Linguistics* 18: 1053–64.
‡ [Eckert, Penelope. n.d. “Why Ethnography?”](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eeckert/PDF/whyethnography.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest 'informal'. It contrasts well with 'official' and implies that the labguage enjoys no supporting structures.

Answer (score 0):

### Take a look at Ethnologue

(You might take a look at https://www.ethnologue.com/ (currently behind a paywall) and use their terminology. They classify languages for a living. The OP's grouping may be somewhat limited to political classifications.)

### Heart language

Wycliffe Bible Translators calls the language that you grow up speaking and understand best a *Heart Language*.

> Minority language speakers in Kenya experience the truth of God's Word when they stop trying to understand Scripture in other languages and start studying it in the language they understand best.

From [Kenyans Understand the Gospel in Their Heart Language](https://www.wycliffe.org/blog/posts/kenyans-understand-the-gospel-in-their-heart-language)

(I have worked in Burkina Faso. The children in the capital city, Ouagadougou, would speak Mòoré every day. Since the official language was French, they would learn French as a foreign language from age five or six, upon entering school. Their birth certificate and other official documents were in French. But in all other realms of daily life, it was Mòoré.)

### Native / mother tongue

These terms are perhaps more neutral than *heart language*. A *mother tongue* is what you learn at your mother's knee. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mother%20tongue) defines it as:

> one's native language

### Quotidian

This is just putting a fancy word on your everyday language.

### Unsuppressed

Since the OP seems to be searching for political terms to classify languages, this is opposite of one of the terms.

Comment: Quotidian seems interesting, but when I think of the Armenian minority here in Turkey, it fails the spec. They learn the Armenian language in minority schools, yet use it only rarely in their daily lives (except special occasions and religious services), which goes mostly in a somewhat flavored but common and official Turkish.

Comment: …or some villages in the eastern Black Sea coast still keep their endemic dialects of Greek, Laz etc. and only speak it when they explicitly want to exclude someone from a conversation :D (like my grandparents-in-law who spoke Greek only when they wanted to hide something from their children)

Comment: I'm sure you can find exceptions to any word proposed. I recommend you go to Ethnologue (you may be able to find a hardcopy at the reference section of a larger library). When you see how it classifies languages, you might find that there are several dimensions that your four-categories have not captured. I think your answer lies in these hidden dimensions.

Comment: I'm not trying to capture every dimension. This is a small personal project :) Thanks anyway, Ethnologue seems like a fantastic resource.